# Spring Security - Access Token without client_secret in parameters

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2, oauth-2.0

I have a spring security oauth2 based application, configured with a JDBC Client Store. As per the OAuth2 specs, client secret must only be used when client-server connections are trustworthy, and certainly not from a web application - where the client secret could be extracted from.

So the question is - how do we configure to let the `/oauth/token` requests with a grant type as "password" produce an access token, without the `client_secret` key in the POST parameters?

This is my authorization server configuration. Pretty basic I would say.

```
<sec:http pattern="/token" create-session="stateless" use-expressions="true" authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager">
        <sec:headers>
            <sec:frame-options policy="DENY" />
            <sec:hsts />
        </sec:headers>
        <sec:csrf disabled="true" />
        <sec:anonymous enabled="false" />
        <sec:http-basic entry-point-ref="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint" />
        <sec:custom-filter ref="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter" before="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" />
        <sec:access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
    </sec:http>
```

Comment: I guess you are confused with 2-legged flow(implicit grant flow) meant for browser based clients which doesn't involve client secret but that is not Password flow.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

According to RFC6749, the OAuth2 Specs, a password grant type must have the client secret passed in either as a request body parameter or as a BASE64 encoded string. The password grant type is not suited for applications that has lesser security or high risk of secrets being exposed to the outer world.

For applications which has a user-agent (web browsers), Implicit Grant Type is the best sought out method.

[Refer the OAuth2 Specs here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749)